# How to insert csv file without double quotes

Tags: sql, csv, bulkinsert, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL 2014.

Here's my current code:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_OKFF
    (
        OKCCY VARCHAR(5),
        OKBRNM VARCHAR(6),
        OKONPX VARCHAR(17),
        OKONPM VARCHAR(17),
        OKFRX VARCHAR(19),
        OKFPX VARCHAR(19),
        OKMRX VARCHAR(17),
        OKMPX VARCHAR(17),
        OKSEQ VARCHAR(3)
    )

BULK INSERT tmp_OKFF
    FROM 'C:\sample.CSV'
    WITH (FORMATFILE='C:\sample.fmt')
```

Here's the sample data in csv:

```
"ABC","0001",-990039739       ,0                ,0                  ,0                  ,0                ,0                ,0
"ABC","    ",-3422054702      ,0                ,481385             ,0                  ,0                ,0                ,0
"XXX","0001",0                ,0                ,0                  ,0                  ,0                ,0                ,0
"ASD","    ",0                ,0                ,0                  ,0                  ,0                ,0                ,0
"JED","0001",21644944         ,0                ,0                  ,0                  ,0                ,0                ,0
"FAQ","    ",74815363         ,0                ,0                  ,11120              ,0                ,0                ,0
"PHP","0002",905175206        ,0                ,0                  ,0                  ,0                ,0                ,0
```

Here's the exact script in format:

```
12.0
10
1 SQLCHAR 0 0 "\"" 0 "" ""
2 SQLCHAR 0 5 "\",\"" 1 OKCCY SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3 SQLCHAR 0 6 "\",\"" 2 OKBRNM SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4 SQLMONEY 0 19 "\",\"" 3 OKONPX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5 SQLMONEY 0 19 "\",\"" 4 OKONPM SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6 SQLMONEY 0 21 "\",\"" 5 OKFRX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7 SQLMONEY 0 21 "\",\"" 6 OKFPX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8 SQLMONEY 0 19 "\",\"" 7 OKMRX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9 SQLMONEY 0 19 "\",\"" 8 OKMPX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10 SQLMONEY 0 5 "\"\r\n" 9 OKSEQ SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I'm getting an error after executing those scripts:

```
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 3 (OKBRNM).
```

Comment: which one is it ? SQL Server or MySQL? It seems to be SQL Server.

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you but it is SQL Server 2014. Thank you!

Comment: No issue. Note that I only have 2012 right now. This is why I change 12.0 to 11.0 in my answer. but it does not mater. Switch back to 12 on your side.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your format file based on you table and sample:

```
11.0                                                       => I am using SS2012
10
1 SQLCHAR 0 1 "\"" 0 ""                                    => change from 0 to 1
2 SQLCHAR 0 3 "\",\"" 1 OKCCY SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS => 5 to 3 (length in your sample)
3 SQLCHAR 0 4 "\"," 2 OKBRNM SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  => remove last after comma and change 6 to 4
4 SQLCHAR 0 17 "," 3 OKONPX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   => change 19 to 17 and remove quote
5 SQLCHAR 0 17 "," 4 OKONPM SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   => change to 17 and remove quotes
6 SQLCHAR 0 19 "," 5 OKFRX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    => change to 19 and remove quotes
7 SQLCHAR 0 19 "," 6 OKFPX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    => change to 19 and remove quotes
8 SQLCHAR 0 17 "," 7 OKMRX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    => change to 17 and remove quotes
9 SQLCHAR 0 17 "," 8 OKMPX SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    => change to 17 and remove quotes
10 SQLCHAR 0 3 "\r" 9 OKSEQ SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   => change to 17 and remove quotes
=> line break
```

Output `select * from tmp_okff`:

```
OKCCY OKBRNM OKONPX             OKONPM              OKFRX               OKFPX               OKMRX           OKMPX               OKSEQ
ABC 0001    -990039739          0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0
ABC         -3422054702         0                   481385              0                   0                   0                   0
XXX 0001    0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0
ASD         0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0
JED 0001    21644944            0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0
FAQ         74815363            0                   0                   11120               0                   0                   0
PHP 0002    905175206           0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0
```

Comment: Hi there. I get an error. Even though I adjusted the column length. Anyway, error is... "Cannot bulk load. Invalid column number in the format file..."

Comment: did you keep 10 (line 2) and do you still have row 1 to 10 below? I suppose you remove all my comments. Don't forget a line break after line 10 or line 9 will be the last line.

Comment: I'm no hustler in SQL 2014. So what I did is I just copied your edited script and removed the comments.

Comment: I always forget to add a line break at the end and I forgot again when I first copied your format file and first tried it. I added it to my answer.